# How do i get the value from my drop down list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to return the selected item and when i debug my code, the view data track list is always null.

How can I assign the value to the view data?

```
public ActionResult EditParcel(int id)
    {
        Parcel parc = _abcSearchService.GetAbcParcel(id);
        List<SelectListItem> TrackList = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Processing", Value = "Processing", Selected = true},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Out for delivery", Value = "Out for delivery"},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Delivered", Value = "Delivered"},
        };
        ViewData["TrackList"] = TrackList;

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditParcel(Parcel parcel)
    {
        try
        {
            var TrackingStatus = ViewData["TrackList"];
            parcel.Tracking_Status = (string)TrackingStatus;
            _abcSearchService.UpdateParcelDetails(parcel);
            return RedirectToAction("Parcel", new { id = parcel.ParcelID, Controller = "ABCParcel" });
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

The drop down list appears on my edit action result, when i select an item from the drop down list to update the item the http post action result happens, the view data TrackList is null.

This is my view

```
﻿﻿   <div class="editor-label">
      <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tracking_Status) %>
   </div>
   <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.DropDownList("TrackList", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["TrackList"])%>
        <%--<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tracking_Status) %>--%>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tracking_Status) %>
```

Comment: Why are you using ViewData at all? Surely you are better off adding TrackList into your Parcel ViewModel?

Comment: Its a project I have to do for university and this is how we have to do it.

Comment: You mean your being taught the wrong way to program? Please show your view model Parcel.

Comment: I don't have a viewmodel

Comment: i thought i would be able to get the tracklist from the viewdata

Comment: But you must have a model or otherwise what is public ActionResult EditParcel(Parcel parcel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following line instead to get the selected value from drop down in your POST action.

```
var TrackingStatus = Request["TrackList"];
```